# How to export several JAVA_OPTS to bash_profile?

Tags: java, configuration, java-11

I want to add two parameters to .bash_profile:

1. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts"
2. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustAnchors="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts"

For this code:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustAnchors="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts"
```

I'm getting error:

> no such file or directory:
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustAnchors=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts